# JLabel.setVisible while running

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have the main class that instantiates a `GridBagLayout` with a `JLabel` visbility set to `false`.

I would like to set the label visible when the program is running, I have tried this but it won't work. It will just display the default layout.

**Main class:**

```
gui = new gui();
gui.display();
gui.label.setVisible(true);
```

**Gridbag layout class:**

```
public JFrame frame;
public JLabel label1; 


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void display(){
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                 gridLayout window = new gridLayout();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


 * Create the application.
 */
public gridLayout() {
    initialize();

}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 1000);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

}

label1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("hi"));
GridBagConstraints gbc_label1 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_label1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
gbc_label1.gridx = 1;
gbc_label1.gridy = 1;
label1.setVisible(false); 
frame.getContentPane().add(label1, gbc_label1);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display a label while a programme is running, right? This has nothing to do with the layout manager.
I give you an example where the label is visible as long as a dialog (representing your task/programme) is displayed; and I hope you can adopt it to your needs. Possibly you have to put the programme/task in an own thread.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Y extends JFrame {
  public static final long serialVersionUID = 100L;

  public Y() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 240);

    JLabel lb= new JLabel("Programme is running ...");
    lb.setVisible(false);
    add(lb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JButton b= new JButton("Launch programme (dialog)");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lb.setVisible(true);
        JDialog dlg= new JDialog(Y.this, "The dialog", true);
        dlg.setSize(100, 100);
        dlg.setVisible(true);
        lb.setVisible(false);
      }
    });
    add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setVisible(true);
  }


  static public void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(Y::new);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response but I'd like to set the label to visible from the main class not the gridlayout class

Comment: If whatever object is used in two classes, you have to pass a reference of that object  from the creating class to the 2nd class. For further help post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).